# Creating a robust Makefile for C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

Consider the following trivial Makefile. Notice that there are two classes with corresponding .h and .cpp files for each.

```
output: main.o class1.o class2.o
    g++ main.o class1.o class2.o -o output

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

class1.o: class1.cpp class1.h
    g++ -c class1.cpp

class2.o: class2.cpp class2.h
    g++ -c class2.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o output
```

Is this Makefile robust? How can I make it more robust? Can someone provide a more robust version of this Makefile? It will be running on a 64 bit Red Hat Linux or CentOS machine.

If it matters, I am using:

-gcc --version 4.8.4 (From the GNU Compiler Collection)

-GDB version: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1 -0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1

Comment: What do you understand as "robust"?  Makefile has some flaws (e.g. no way to set mandatory and optional flags, no automatic dependency tracking, no VPATH builds).

Comment: Why do you have a Makefile if you're using CMake?!

Comment: @Biffen - I have to send the application to someone else without CMake.

Comment: @ensc - More robust == Will work properly on my professors Linux machine. I don't know what any of that stuff means, but this assignment is due very soon. Could you please edit my code with those changes?

Comment: Don't your header files get included in more than one place?

Comment: @aschepler - I don't know. I followed a simply tutorial online, and this is what the example looked like. Is something incorrect? This needs to work on a linux machine.

Comment: Doesn't `main.o` depend upon `class1.h` and `class2.h`?

Comment: @aschepler I am requesting that someone provide the correct and more robust version as I don't have time to learn so much in so little time.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst Yes!

Comment: At the very very minimum this will run the clean target by default, on a clean environment this will throw a bunch of errors.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst it has been #include in main.cpp

Comment: @johannes tbh I have no idea what that means. I have used UNIX for 2 days of my life.

Answer (score 2):

I would write something like

```
CXX = g++
# mandatory build flags
AM_CXXFLAGS = -Wall -W -std=gnu++11
# optional build flags
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -Werror

# mandatory link flags
AM_LDFLAGS = -Wl,-as-neeeded

output: main.o class1.o class2.o
    ${CXX} ${AM_LDFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} $(filter %.o,$^) -o $@

%: %.cpp
    ${CXX} ${AM_CXXFLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} $< -c -o $@

class1.o: class1.cpp class1.h
class2.o: class2.cpp class2.h
```

- the `*FLAGS` are following automake notation: `AM_*` mean mandatory flags, the normal flags contain local settings (e.g. debugging or optimiziation).

  Usually, `AM_CPPFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` with preprocessor flags (`-I ...`) should be used too but I omitted them here
- the `output` target might need `${LIBS}` too which have been omitted here
- dependency tracking is more tricky and **not** implemented; you will have to play with `-dM` compiler option here...

When your program consists only of the listed 5 files, you can write

```
output_SOURCES = main.c class1.c class2.c class1.h class2.h

output: ${output_SOURCES}
        ${CXX} ${AM_CXXFLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} ${AM_LDFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} $(filter %.cpp,$^) -o $@ ${LIBS}
```

directly.

EDIT:

For automatic dependency tracking, you can write

```
DEPGENFLAGS = \
    -MD -MF ${@D}/.${@F}.d -MT '$@'

%: %.cpp
    ${CXX} ${DEPGENFLAGS} ${AM_CXXFLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} $< -c -o $@

-include .deps.main.o.d
-include .deps.class1.o.d
-include .deps.class2.o.d
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your original makefile is far off the mark. I've just made a few additions:

1. Added a default `all` target - it's good to be explicit
2. Use the `CXXFLAGS` environment variable in all the calls to g++
3. Make `main.o` depend upon `class1.h` and `class2.h` as discussed
4. Specify that `clean` is a `PHONY` target just to be on the safe side if you add build artifact called `clean`

---

```
ALL := output

all : $(ALL) 

output: main.o class1.o class2.o
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) main.o class1.o class2.o -o output

main.o: main.cpp class1.h class2.h
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp

class1.o: class1.cpp class1.h
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c class1.cpp

class2.o: class2.cpp class2.h
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c class2.cpp

.PHONY : clean

clean:
    rm *.o output
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make it more robust?

Use implicit rules, keep it simple.

```
LDLIBS+=-lstdc++
output: main.o class1.o class2.o

clean:
    rm *.o output
```

Comment: this is so short! are there any disadvantages to this implementation compared to other solutions given?